# Unit test of jQuery datatable's callback method in Angular 6

Tags: jquery, angular, unit-testing, datatables, karma-jasmine

Is there anyway to test callback method of jQuery datatable in Angular 6 using karma/jasmine?

I want to test following method's footer callback but I can't figure out any way to do so. I am new in unit testing and cannot finding anything helpful on web.

```
 initializeBugIndexPageSetting() {
    let self = this;
    $('example').DataTable({
        'footerCallback': function (row, data, start, end, display) {
            const api = this.api();
            // Remove the formatting to get integer data for summation
            const intVal = function (i) {
                if (i === 'N/A') {
                    return 0;
                }
                return i * 1;
            };
            // Total over this page
            const pageInProgrssToResolved = api
                .column(14, { page: 'current' })
                .data()
                .reduce(function (a, b) {
                    return intVal(a) + intVal(b);
                }, 0);
            const pageCount = api
                .column(5, { page: 'current' })
                .data().count();
           // Update footer           
            $(api.column(14).footer()).html((pageInProgrssToResolved / pageCount).toFixed(2));
        }
    });
}
```

Little help and guidance.

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest putting the content of the callback to a seperate method, since this new function is very easy to unit test.

And as a second test I would suggest to test the initializeBugIndexPageSetting function by adding a jasmine spy on the new function that is then called in the footerCallback and you can just check if it has been called (.toHaveBeenCalledTimes(1) on the spy after calling theinitializeBugIndexPageSetting function).

You can find a valuable tutorial here: https://scriptverse.academy/tutorials/jasmine-createspy-createspyobj.html

Comment: as you said that but callback functionality in a new function, then it would be easy to test but exactly then how and what kind of unit test I can write for it as 'footerCallback': function (row, data, start, end, display)'  is  passed in data table so I clearly cant get it. Can you please write some sample test that would be really helpful.